# Residue of Fractional Function.

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

$P(z), Q(z)$ : regular analytic function.

$f(z):=\dfrac{P(z)}{Q(z)}$.

$P(z_0) \neq 0, Q(z_0)=0$ and $z_0$ is $1$st order of $f$.

Then, is residue of $f$ at $z=z_0$ equal to $\dfrac{P(z_0)}{Q'(z_0)}$ ?

My darivation is following.

\begin{align*}
\text{Res}(z_0,f)
&=\lim_{z \to z_0} (z-z_0)\dfrac{P(z)}{Q(z)}\\
&=_{\text{L'Hôpital's rule}} \lim_{z \to z_0} \dfrac{P(z)+(z-z_0)P'(z)}{Q'(z)}\\
&=\dfrac{P(z_0)}{Q'(z_0)}.
\end{align*}

Is this idea correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is correct if $f$ has a simple pole at $z_0$, i.e. if $Q'(z_0) \ne 0$. Alternative derivations are
$$
\operatorname{Res}(z_0,f) =\lim_{z \to z_0} (z-z_0)\frac{P(z)}{Q(z)} \\
= \lim_{z \to z_0} \frac{P(z)}{\frac{Q(z)-Q(z_0)}{z-z_0}} = \frac{P(z_0)}{Q'(z_0)} \, ,
$$
using the definition of the derivative, or
$$
\frac{P(z)}{Q(z)} = \frac{P(z_0) + O(z- z_0)}{Q'(z)(z-z_0) + O(z-z_0)^2} \\
= \frac{P(z_0)}{Q'(z_0)} \frac{1}{z-z_0} + O(1) \, ,
$$
using asymptotic development at $z=z_0$.

Note that the condition $P(z_0) \ne 0$ is not needed as long as $Q$ has a simple zero at $z_0$: If $P(z_0) = 0$ then the formula gives $\operatorname{Res}(z_0,f) = 0$, which is correct because $f$ has a removable singularity at $z_0$.